# How to use google script on google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just got this script from youtube. Can anyone teach me how can I use this on both column 6 and column 7? I really don't have a single idea I'm just using this for my small business to make my tracker easier. Thank you in advance!

```
function onEdit (e){
if (e.range.columnStart != 6 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a little twist of the original logic makes it a little slower but easier to write.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart >5 && e.range.columnStart < 8 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    sh.hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)